# Does requests.codes.ok include a 304?

Tags: python, python-requests, http-status-code-304

I have a program which uses the requests module to send a get request which (correctly) responds with a 304 "Not Modified". After making the request, I check to make sure `response.status_code == requests.codes.ok`, but this check fails. Does requests not consider a 304 as "ok"?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can check actual codes [in the source](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/status_codes.py). `ok` means 200 only.

Comment: Thanks - Ha - I never realized that the '✓' character was also mapped to 200.

Comment: this answer is FALSE, both according to the documentation [http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.ok] and according to the source [http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/models/#Response.raise_for_status]

Comment: @MattiLyra you're actually incorrect here. `requests.codes.ok` is not the same as `requests.models.Response.ok`. You're correct that `requests.models.Response.ok` does indeed return true for values of 200 <= status_code < 400, but `requests.codes.ok` is just the value 200. You can see for yourself with `import requests; print(requests.codes.ok)`

Answer (score 49):

There is a property called [`ok`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/?highlight=OK#requests.Response.ok) in the `Response` object that returns `True` if the status code is not a `4xx` or a `5xx`.

So you could do the following:

```
if response.ok:
    # 304 is included
```

The code of this property is pretty simple:

```
@property
def ok(self):
    try:
        self.raise_for_status()
    except HTTPError:
        return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 4):

You can check the implementation of requests.status code here [source code](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/status_codes.py).
The implementation allows you to access all/any kind of **status_codes** as follow:

```
import requests
import traceback
url = "https://google.com"
req = requests.get(url)
try:
    if req.status_code == requests.codes['ok']: # Check the source code for all the codes
        print('200')
    elif req.status_code == requests.codes['not_modified']: # 304
        print("304")
    elifreq.status_code == requests.codes['not_found']: # 404
        print("404")
    else:
        print("None of the codes")
except:
    traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
```

In conclusion, you can access any request-response like demonstrated. I am sure there are better ways but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`.ok` **"..If the status code is between 200 and 400, this will return True."**

[mentioned in source code as:](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L696)

> """Returns True if :attr:`status_code` is less than 400, False if not.
> This attribute checks if the status code of the response is between
> 400 and 600 to see if there was a client error or a server error. If
> the status code is between 200 and 400, this will return True. This
> is **not** a check to see if the response code is `200 OK`.
> """